# Add More Attachments and Stop at a Certain Number

Tags: jquery, html

I create a button to add more attachments.  It works well and I want to stop at a certain number, for example at 5 attachments, they cannot attach anymore.  I set `i <6;`, but it doesn't stop at 5 attachments.  Live Code http://jsfiddle.net/abcid/e1c3xu01/

HTML

```
<div class="attachFile"><input type="file" /></div><button id="addNew">Add</button>
<p></p>
<div class="attachField"></div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(
    function()
        {
            var i=0;
            $('#addNew').click(
                function()
                    {
                        i++; i <6;
                        $('.attachField').append( '<div class="attachFile"><input type="file" /></div>' );


            }); //end click

        }); //end ready
```

2. Different way, I like to disappear the Add button after 5 attachments, but my syntax below doesn't work out.  Live code [http://jsfiddle.net/abcid/f2wc6srm/](http://jsfiddle.net/abcid/f2wc6srm/2/)

JS

```
$(document).ready(
    function()
        {
            var i=0;
            $('#addNew').click(
                function()
                    {
                        i++;
                        $('.attachField').append( '<div class="attachFile"><input type="file" /></div>' );

            if( i = 5)
            {
            $('#addNew').hide;
            }
            }); //end click

        }
); //end ready
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add `if` statement and check whether i < 6

```
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        var i = 0;
        $('#addNew').click(
            function () {
                if (i < 6) {
                    i++;
                    $('.attachField').append('<div class="attachFile"><input type="file" /></div>');
                }     
            }

        ); //end click
    }
); //end ready
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Mohsen!  It works perfectly.  In  my second issue, I did the same thing, but instead of (i<6), I use (i=6),I am wondering why it doesn't work.  Please take a look at my second issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just edited and the second issue works well.

```
$(document).ready(
    function()
        {
            var i=0;
            $('#addNew').click(
                function()
                    {
                        i++;
                        $('.attachField').append( '<div class="attachFile"><input type="file" /></div>' );

            if( i >= 5)
            {
            $('#addNew').hide();
            }
            }); //end click

        }
); //end ready
```

[Live code](http://jsfiddle.net/abcid/f2wc6srm/3/)